# How to stop auto redirection URL,when automating the Web based application using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I'm trying to navigate to URL `https://www.lambdatest.com/` but system automatically redirect to URL `https://www.lambdatest.com/pricing` page so that my testcase are failing.

even tried on incognito but redirection happen and unable to connect with selenium gird.

```java
public class TestScenario {

    WebDriver driver;
    JavascriptExecutor js;
    String currentWindow;

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({ "browser", "browserVersion", "platform" })
    public void setUp(String browser, String browserVersion, String platform) {

        String username = "XXXXXX";
        String accessKey = "XXXXXX";
        /*
         * HashMap<String, Object> ltOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>(); //
         * ltOptions.put("username", "XXXXXX"); 
         * ltOptions.put("accessKey",
         * "XXXXX");
         * ltOptions.put("visual", true); ltOptions.put("video", true);
         * ltOptions.put("network", true); ltOptions.put("build", "Build 0.1");
         * ltOptions.put("project", "Selenium Advanced"); ltOptions.put("name",
         * "Retest"); ltOptions.put("tunnel", true); ltOptions.put("w3c", true);
         * ltOptions.put("plugin", "java-testNG");
         * 
         * if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) { ChromeOptions browserOptions = new
         * ChromeOptions();
         * 
         * browserOptions.setPlatformName(platform);
         * browserOptions.setBrowserVersion(browserVersion);
         * browserOptions.setCapability("LT:Options", ltOptions);
         * 
         * try { driver = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("https://" + username + ":" +
         * accessKey + "@hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub"), browserOptions);
         * 
         * } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         * e.printStackTrace(); } driver.manage().window().maximize();
         * driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
         * 
         * } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("MicrosoftEdge")) {
         * 
         * EdgeOptions browserOptions = new EdgeOptions();
         * 
         * browserOptions.setPlatformName(platform);
         * browserOptions.setBrowserVersion(browserVersion);
         * browserOptions.setCapability("LT:Options", ltOptions);
         * 
         * try { driver = new RemoteWebDriver( new URL("https://" + username + ":" +
         * accessKey + "@hub.lambdatest.com/wd/hub"), browserOptions);
         * 
         * } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         * e.printStackTrace(); } driver.manage().window().maximize();
         * driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
         * 
         * } else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid browser name: " +
         * browser); }
         */

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("MicrosoftEdge")) {

            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        }

    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testcase1() {
        /*
         * 1. Navigate to https://www.lambdatest.com/.
         */

        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/");

        /*
         * 2. Perform an explicit wait till the time all the elements in the DOM are
         * available. 3. Scroll to the WebElement ‘SEE ALL INTEGRATIONS’ using the
         * scrollIntoView() method. You are free to use any of the available web
         * locators (e.g., XPath, CssSelector, etc.)
         */

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*")));

        WebElement seeAllIntegrations = driver.findElement(By.linkText("SEE ALL INTEGRATIONS"));
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", seeAllIntegrations);

        /*
         * 4. Click on the link and ensure that it opens in a new Tab.
         * 
         * 5. Save the window handles in a List (or array). Print the window handles of
         * the opened windows (now there are two windows open).
         */

        currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

        Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
        ac.moveToElement(seeAllIntegrations).contextClick().build().perform();
        ac.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

        Set<String> allOpenedWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

        List<String> handles = new ArrayList<String>(allOpenedWindows);

        for (String child : handles) {
            if (!currentWindow.equals(child))
                driver.switchTo().window(child);

        }

        /*
         * 6. Verify whether the URL is the same as the expected URL (if not, throw an
         * Assert).
         */

        String expectedUrl = "https://www.lambdatest.com/integrations";
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), expectedUrl, "URL is not the same as expected.");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void testcase2() {
        /*
         * 7. On that page, scroll to the page where the WebElement (Codeless
         * Automation) is present.
         */

        WebElement codelessAutomation = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[5]/a"));

        codelessAutomation.click();

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", codelessAutomation);

        /*
         * 8. Click the ‘LEARN MORE’ link for Testing Whiz. The page should open in the
         * same window.
         */

        WebElement learnMore = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"codeless_row\"]/div/div[4]/a"));
        learnMore.click();
        /*
         * 9. Check if the title of the page is ‘TestingWhiz Integration |
         * LambdaTest’.If not, raise an Assert.
         */

        String expectedTitle = "TestingWhiz Integration | LambdaTest";
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), expectedTitle, "Title is not as expected.");

        /*
         * 10. Close the current window using the window handle [which we obtained in
         * step (5)]
         */
        driver.close();
        driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);

        int currentWindowCount = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
        System.out.println("Current window count: " + currentWindowCount);

    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void testCase3() {

        /*
         * 12. On the current window, set the URL to https://www.lambdatest.com/blog.
         * 13. Click on the ‘Community’ link and verify whether the URL is
         * https://community.lambdatest.com/. 14. Close the current browser window.
         */

        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/blog");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"menu-item-10121\"]/a")).click();

        String expectedUrl = "https://community.lambdatest.com/";

        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), expectedUrl, "URL is not the same as expected.");

        driver.close();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    
    <suite name="LambdaTest Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
      
        <test name="Test Scenario 1">
            <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
            <parameter name="browserVersion" value="86.0" />
            <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
            <classes>
                <class name="seleniumAdvanced_Assignment.TestScenario" />
            </classes>
        </test>
      
        <test name="Test Scenario 2">
            <parameter name="browser" value="MicrosoftEdge" />
            <parameter name="browserVersion" value="87.0" />
            <parameter name="platform" value="macOS Sierra" />
            <classes>
                <class name="seleniumAdvanced_Assignment.TestScenario" />
            </classes>
        </test> </suite>
```

If trying to connect grid below error throwing

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.8.0
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jul 30, 2023 3:07:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer createTracer
INFO: Using OpenTelemetry for tracing

===============================================
LambdaTest Suite
Total tests run: 6, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 6
Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 2
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ohh, in that case, you have to wait for to open completely the default application https://www.lambdatest.com/pricing, than what you to do is pass your expected URL https://www.lambdatest.com/ through driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com") and then hit enter through this code driver.find_element_by_name("Value").send_keys(Keys.ENTER) and perform the remaining actions.
```